# how to increase ant permgen size?

Tags: maven, ant, junit

how to increase ant permgen size? I have given in ANT_OPTS as

> -Xms768m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=128m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

question
1)After specifying above setting in system environment, still i am getting outof memeory error for ant target for junit.

```
Caught an exception while logging the end of the build.  Exception was:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

2) when i type in command promt to see what is path for ant_opts, echo %ant_opts% it shows only

> -Xmx512m

and other parts skips. is something wrong in my path?
Note: i am using command prompt to run ant target.

Comment: Check that you don't have any other variable (like `JAVA_OPTS`) overriding it.

Comment: Are you running this through some sort of container? Perhaps it isn't passing the values on.

Comment: no i dont have any other OPTS. I am running integration test which takes longer time to execute test cases.using command prompt to run ant target for junit report.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

go to my computer->right click->properties->Advanced->environment variables->New(in system/user variable)->

enter

```
Varible name: ANT_OPTS
Varible Value : -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

Note:

1. configure values according to your system memory size.
2. This config for windows, for other OS config accordingly

For MAC:

in Terminal, goto pom.xml path in project, run below command:

export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m" Note: Size is based on system RAM.
I used maven instead of old Ant. use MAVEN_OPTS/ANT_OPTS for maven/ant config.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, that doesn't work on my computer: a Mac running OS X!

Comment: on mine neither (ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: Should the mac instructions be `ANT_OPTS` not `MAVEN_OPTS`?

Answer (score 3):

What does your test do? Does it call a recursive method?

Also, the values that you enter for your test will override any system setting. Try this in your call to junit in your Ant script:

```
<junit fork="yes" maxmemory="1024">
```

Comment: Whats the default if you don't supply `maxmemory`?

Comment: Great answer! I found that I was getting an out of memory error because our `<junit forkmode>` had been changed. By default, it's `perTest`, but if it's changed to something else (e.g. `once`) then this can cause OutOfMemory exceptions since junit doesn't start a new VM instance for each test.

Answer (score 1):

for my junit ant target I just set `fork="true"` that way a new jvm would be initiated for the junit tasks, there's also `forkmode="perBatch"`or `"perTest"`, worked for me!