# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while generating reports

Tags: ant, junit

I am trying to generate HTML reports from txt format reports that were generated after executing junit test cases. On running ant command with build.xml in proper location, I am getting  below error message

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I tried increasing heap space by `ANT_OPTS=-Xmx1024m` command.

Still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Use `export JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m` before starting Ant, because ANT_OPTS may be overriden by JAVA_OPTS if they are set system wise

Comment: In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618450/out-of-memory-error-in-ant) thread they had the same problem and it appeared to be an endless loop. Would you give it a try and check your tests?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387380/how-to-increase-ant-permgen-size?rq=1) thread also suggests some solutions that you can try